# Render Truetype fonts with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, go

I am starting to learn OpenGL now, using the **Go programming language** (I just couldn't get working with C/C++ on my Windows machine), and so far I've managed to display some rotating cubes in the screen with textures mainly copying and pasting code from tutorials. I've learned a lot, though, but I just can't get some text on the screen with this code that I wrote on my own. I've looked up many tutorials and questions but nothing seems to work, and I suspect there is something wrong with the vertices because I'm pretty sure the textures coordinates are correct and still there's nothing showing up in the screen. Here's the code:

```
package game

import (
  "fmt"
  "io/ioutil"
  "image"
  "image/draw"
  "github.com/go-gl/gl/v3.3-core/gl"
  mgl "github.com/go-gl/mathgl/mgl32"
  "github.com/golang/freetype/truetype"
  "golang.org/x/image/font"
  "golang.org/x/image/math/fixed"
)

type GameFont struct {
  loaded bool
  vao uint32
  vbo VBOData
  pix float32
  Texture *Texture
  Shader ShaderProgram
}


// Load a TrueType font from a file and generate a texture 
// with all important characters.
func (f *GameFont) Load(path string, pix float32) {
  contents, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Could not read font file: " + path)
    panic(err)
  }
  fontFace, err := truetype.Parse(contents)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Could not parse font file: " + path)
    panic(err)
  }

  // Create a texture for the characters
  // Find the next power of 2 for the texture size
  size := nextP2(int(pix * 16))
  fg, bg := image.White, image.Black
  rgba := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, size, size))

  draw.Draw(rgba, rgba.Bounds(), bg, image.ZP, draw.Src)
  d := &font.Drawer{
    Dst: rgba,
    Src: fg,
    Face: truetype.NewFace(fontFace, &truetype.Options{
      Size: float64(pix),
      DPI: 72,
      Hinting: font.HintingNone,
    }),
  }

  // Some GL preps
  gl.GenVertexArrays(1, &f.vao)
  gl.BindVertexArray(f.vao)
  f.vbo.Create()
  f.vbo.Bind()

  f.Shader = newShaderProgram("data/shaders/font.vert", "data/shaders/font.frag")
  f.Shader.Use()
  f.Shader.SetUniform("tex", 0)

  // Create vertex data (and coordinates in the texture) for each character
  // All characters below 32 are useless
  for i := 32; i < 128; i++ {
    c := string(rune(i))
    x, y := i % 16, i / 16

    // Draw the character on the texture
    d.Dot = fixed.P(x * int(pix), y * int(pix))
    d.DrawString(c)

    // Vertices
    quads := []float32{
      0,    0,
      0,    pix,
      pix,  0,
      pix,  pix,
    }

    norm := func(n int) float32 {
      return float32(n) / 16.0
    }

    // Texture coordinates (normalized)
    texQuads := []float32{
      norm(x),      1.0 - norm(y + 1),
      norm(x),      1.0 - norm(y),
      norm(x + 1),  1.0 - norm(y + 1),
      norm(x + 1),  1.0 - norm(y),
    }

    for v := 0; v < 8; v += 2 {
      vQuads, vTexQuads := quads[v:(v+2)], texQuads[v:(v+2)]

      // Data is like (X, Y, U, V)
      f.vbo.AppendData(vQuads, 2)
      f.vbo.AppendData(vTexQuads, 2)
    }
  }

  // Upload data to GPU and we're done
  f.Texture = newTextureFromRGBA(rgba)
  f.Texture.Bind()
  f.Texture.SetGLParam(gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR)
  f.Texture.SetGLParam(gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR)
  f.Texture.Upload()

  f.vbo.UploadData(gl.STATIC_DRAW)

  gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(0)
  gl.VertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 4*4, gl.PtrOffset(0))
  gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(1)
  gl.VertexAttribPointer(1, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 4*4, gl.PtrOffset(2*4))

  f.loaded = true
}

// Render a text using the font
func (f *GameFont) Render(text string, x, y int, pix float32, color mgl.Vec4) {
  if !f.loaded {
    return
  }

  gl.Disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST)
  gl.Enable(gl.BLEND)
  gl.BlendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
  gl.BindVertexArray(f.vao)

  f.Shader.Use()
  f.Shader.SetUniform("projection", mgl.Ortho2D(0, _screen.Width, 0, _screen.Height))
  f.Shader.SetUniform("color", color)

  f.Texture.Bind()

  scale := pix / f.pix
  for i := 0; i < len(text); i++ {
    index := rune(text[i])
    model := mgl.Ident4().Mul4(mgl.Scale3D(scale, scale, 0))
    model = model.Add(mgl.Translate3D(float32(x) + float32(i) * pix, float32(y), 0))
    f.Shader.SetUniform("model", model)
    gl.DrawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, (32-index)*4, 4)
  }

  gl.Enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST)
  gl.Disable(gl.BLEND)
}
```

Here's the shaders:

**Vertex shader**

```
#version 330
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 model;

layout (location = 0) in vec2 vert;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 vertTexCoord;

out vec2 fragTexCoord;

void main() {
  fragTexCoord = vertTexCoord;
  gl_Position = projection * model * vec4(vert, 0, 1);
}
```

**Fragment shader**

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform vec4 color;

in vec2 fragTexCoord;
out vec4 outputColor;

void main() {
  outputColor = color * texture(tex, fragTexCoord);
}
```

Every "component" of the GameFont struct is working properly (I've used them with the rotating cubes), so every function calls the GL corresponding one.

Also the texture is being drawed correctly, I've saved it to the disk and it looks like this:

[image]

And still, there's no text on the screen.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://github.com/golang/freetype/blob/master/example/freetype/main.go? I'm currently working on the same thing, same language.

Comment: @sixFingers yes, I've actually used the "drawer" example. Anyways, the problem was in my rendering code, and I've been able to solve it. It is working now, let me know if you need any help.

Comment: happy to hear you solved it. I did, too. In the end, i used a list of triangles with corresponding uvs. One single draw for an entire textBox.